# Spring Boot version changed from 1.5.8 to 2.0.0

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

while trying to migrate to spring boot version 2.0, I faced the following issue when tried to run Junits. The same unit tests used to work on the spring boot version 1.5.8 but after changing the version they started to fail. The following is the stack trace to the issue. Could you please let me know what is the root cause for the same?

> Application run failed java.lang.IllegalStateException:Error
>   processing condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)|at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)|at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)|Caused
>   by:java.lang.IllegalStateException:@ConditionalOnMissingBean did not
>   specify a bean using type,name or annotation and the attempt to deduce
>   the bean'stype failed|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:390)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.(OnBeanCondition.java:380)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:114)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)|...42
>   common frames omitted|Caused
>   by:org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException:Failed
>   to deduce bean type for
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:443)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:427)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.(OnBeanCondition.java:374)|...44
>   common frames omitted|Caused
>   by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer|at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)|at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)|at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)|at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)|at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:264)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:437)|...46
>   common frames omitted|2018-05-10 09:32:00,391
>   INFO[main]GenericWebApplicationContext[]>:Closing
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
>   @71f bfa85:startup date[Thu May 10 09:31:59 IST 2018];root of context
>   hierarchy
>
> 2018-05-10 09:32:00,393 ERROR[main]TestContextManager[]>:Caught
>   exception while allowing
>   TestExecutionListener[org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener
>   @3e3894 ce]to prepare test
>   instance[com.sap.bs.businesslogging.util.ConfigValidatorTest @748500f
>   3]java.lang.IllegalStateException:Failed to load ApplicationContext|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)|at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)|at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)|at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)|at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)|Caused
>   by:java.lang.IllegalStateException:Error processing condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)|at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)|at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)|at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)|...26
>   common frames omitted|Caused
>   by:java.lang.IllegalStateException:@ConditionalOnMissingBean did not
>   specify a bean using type,name or annotation and the attempt to deduce
>   the bean'stype failed|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:390)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.(OnBeanCondition.java:380)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:114)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)|...42
>   common frames omitted|Caused
>   by:org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException:Failed
>   to deduce bean type for
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:443)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:427)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.(OnBeanCondition.java:374)|...44
>   common frames omitted|Caused
>   by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer|at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)|at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)|at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)|at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)|at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:264)|at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:437)|...46
>   common frames omitted

Comment: Looks straightforward: `Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`

Answer (score 2):

As Roddy pointed out, the error happened due to missing `org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`.

Do you have any Spring Data dependency in your `POM.xml`? For instance, `spring-data-jpa`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration` that was triggered (when it shouldn't be) and it had problem with missing class on classpath `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`. However I did not include spring-data in my dependencies, so I had to exclude it. 
Here's sample code how to do it in gradle:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-data-commons'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` and remove the one on `spring-data-redis` if you have one.